# Search and Replace within one file

Tags: ruby, search, replace

i'm new to Ruby and i'm trying to use RegEx to do multiple search and replaces in an input text file, however my code isn't working, i think i understand why it doesn't work but i don't know the syntax i need to make it work. 
Heres my code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# open file to read and write
file = File.open("input.txt", "r+")
# get the contents of the file
contents = file.read
file.close

reassign = contents.gsub(/\w+/, '£££££')

# save it out as a new file
new_file = File.new("output.txt")
new_file.write(reassign)
new_file.close
```

this is the error messages:

```
C:/Users/parsonsr/RubymineProjects/Test 3/test3.rb:14:in `write': not opened for writing (IOError)
    from C:/Users/parsonsr/RubymineProjects/Test 3/test3.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

i tried using an array to pass each line through and change whats relevant but then it only saves whats in the array to the output not the rest of the file.
I either need it to change the text thats already there within one file or change the text then save the file with the new changes made into an output file, whichever is easiest.
Hope this makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open). Note that File#open receives mode "r" by default.
So the answer is: change

```
File.new("output.txt")
```

to

```
File.new("output.txt", "w")
```

Another thing you can do in Ruby is:

```
File.write("output.txt", reassign)
```

Or:

```
File.open("output.txt", "w")
```

Also, i don't know what's the purpose, but consider a big file, you might want to read batch of lines and write them to the output file each time, not read all at once to the memory.